# apply function to be used with a user defined function

Tags: r

I have following matrix:

```
2001 2002 2003 2004 2005 Start End
0.1  0.1 0.5  NA    1    2002 2004
0.2   NA   1   0.1  0.8  2001 2003
```

is there a way to use apply (matrix,1,Fun) with a user defined function to calculate the the maximum for each row based by taking into account only the columns between Start and End returning the following result:

```
0.5
1
```

I would like to avoid using a loop to be faster.

output of

> dput(matrix)

:

```
    structure(c("0.874019503593445", "0.86563766002655", "0.876677572727203", 
"0.87995857000351", "0.857958316802979", "0.876143276691437", 
"0.862336575984955", "0.853970944881439", "0.846048414707184", 
"0.859661996364594", "0.834502220153809", "0.852427303791046", 
"0.822492599487305", "0.813440501689911", "0.76100218296051", 
"0.820943117141724", "0.764204323291779", "0.785735309123993", 
"0.817545235157013", "0.81278395652771", "0.723827838897705", 
"0.785534679889679", "0.7496058344841", "0.777993083000183", 
"0.817822515964508", "0.812875807285309", "0.712881326675415", 
"0.756305634975433", "0.743959069252014", "0.769496917724609", 
"0.810760021209717", "0.80568391084671", "0.693456709384918", 
"0.727128684520721", "0.729035794734955", "0.756283938884735", 
"0.807579278945923", "0.802182674407959", "0.684139847755432", 
"0.704573571681976", "0.724795341491699", "0.756382524967194", 
"0.804896593093872", "0.799209952354431", "0.678259372711182", 
"0.702164053916931", "0.718267142772675", "0.751578271389008", 
"0.799822628498077", "0.793913602828979", "0.665935218334198", 
"0.694310545921326", "0.708142817020416", "0.743632614612579", 
"0.793001770973206", "0.787713170051575", "0.647054612636566", 
"0.677092432975769", "0.694708645343781", "0.73238867521286", 
"0.789437413215637", "0.784072935581207", "0.63111686706543", 
"0.65886777639389", "0.684714734554291", "0.724371314048767", 
"0.843812942504883", "0.839520990848541", "0.773352861404419", 
"0.779657006263733", "0.788854360580444", "0.809786915779114", 
"0.877531945705414", "0.873724162578583", "0.842803955078125", 
"0.855762183666229", "0.850594639778137", "0.862756550312042", 
"0.880029559135437", "0.873950898647308", "0.870781242847443", 
"0.866772592067719", "0.858940064907074", "0.868877649307251", 
"0.853329718112946", "0.855516672134399", "0.823540806770325", 
"0.830541551113129", "0.830010652542114", "0.819457948207855", 
"0.827873051166534", "0.822244465351105", "0.773614823818207", 
"0.797049939632416", "0.751720309257507", "0.768605947494507", 
"0.766616880893707", "0.756787300109863", "0.566888153553009", 
"0.586601614952087", "0.581688940525055", "0.617175340652466", 
"0.718824028968811", "0.706149041652679", "0.378618478775024", 
"0.391031503677368", "0.446874260902405", "0.480405360460281", 
"0.795396089553833", "0.786651313304901", "0.678426802158356", 
"0.685614347457886", "0.696484625339508", "0.716927468776703", 
"0.810630321502686", "0.803157091140747", "0.759427130222321", 
"0.744760811328888", "0.755291044712067", "0.770642638206482", 
"0.820476651191711", "0.813506543636322", "0.785165846347809", 
"0.786000072956085", "0.795400500297546", "0.804410338401794", 
"0.845328569412231", "0.839278340339661", "0.807336449623108", 
"0.812321186065674", "0.834664046764374", "0.842991709709167", 
"0.860692620277405", "0.855358898639679", "0.866921603679657", 
"0.871038675308228", "0.857144951820374", "0.862971782684326", 
"0.8672935962677", "0.862846493721008", "0.8633052110672", "0.86958372592926", 
"0.854647994041443", "0.86020702123642", "0.865541696548462", 
"0.861103653907776", "0.865747451782227", "0.872776210308075", 
"0.854572534561157", "0.855659008026123", "0.866914212703705", 
"0.862517952919006", "0.872524857521057", "0.878805994987488", 
"0.85886561870575", "0.858219861984253", "0.878345549106598", 
"0.874269723892212", "0.888411402702332", "0.892201542854309", 
"0.874585866928101", "0.876360237598419", "0.884132504463196", 
"0.88018411397934", "0.89205276966095", "0.894862949848175", 
"0.879017233848572", "0.884612858295441", "0.884777724742889", 
"0.880885481834412", "0.896000146865845", "0.901106178760529", 
"0.880709052085876", "0.884517729282379", "0.88497519493103", 
"0.881140291690826", "0.889452517032623", "0.893048226833344", 
"0.875616371631622", "0.879878103733063", "0.879022836685181", 
"0.875194191932678", "0.866267263889313", "0.871312737464905", 
"0.859204828739166", "0.866826951503754", "0.868023276329041", 
"0.86393541097641", "0.841034770011902", "0.847780704498291", 
"0.837899088859558", "0.848678171634674", "0.862271964550018", 
"0.85805755853653", "0.829115211963654", "0.831472992897034", 
"0.824896633625031", "0.836804389953613", "0.860555946826935", 
"0.856406271457672", "0.82395201921463", "0.818446636199951", 
"0.817780017852783", "0.829550802707672", "0.871107757091522", 
"0.867229819297791", "0.838211238384247", "0.848833799362183", 
"0.838103652000427", "0.852475762367249", "0.835780441761017", 
"0.831098616123199", "0.74629545211792", "0.763430953025818", 
"0.768242657184601", "0.796047866344452", "2001.06.09", "2001.06.14", 
"2001.06.13", "2001.07.27", "2001.06.30", "2001.06.10", "2001.10.03", 
"2001.09.27", "2001.09.18", "2001.10.29", "2001.10.01", "2001.10.01"
), .Dim = c(6L, 38L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("SM_2001.01.01", 
"SM_2001.01.11", "SM_2001.01.21", "SM_2001.02.01", "SM_2001.02.11", 
"SM_2001.02.21", "SM_2001.03.01", "SM_2001.03.11", "SM_2001.03.21", 
"SM_2001.04.01", "SM_2001.04.11", "SM_2001.04.21", "SM_2001.05.01", 
"SM_2001.05.11", "SM_2001.05.21", "SM_2001.06.01", "SM_2001.06.11", 
"SM_2001.06.21", "SM_2001.07.01", "SM_2001.07.11", "SM_2001.07.21", 
"SM_2001.08.01", "SM_2001.08.11", "SM_2001.08.21", "SM_2001.09.01", 
"SM_2001.09.11", "SM_2001.09.21", "SM_2001.10.01", "SM_2001.10.11", 
"SM_2001.10.21", "SM_2001.11.01", "SM_2001.11.11", "SM_2001.11.21", 
"SM_2001.12.01", "SM_2001.12.11", "SM_2001.12.21", "SOS", "EOS"
)))
```

Comment: What is `start` and `end` in that example? `SOS` and `EOS`?

Comment: yes exactly! StartofSeason and EndofSeason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a hint: you should consider storing your data in a data.frame with a tidy structure.

Using the whole `tidyverse` and `lubridate` and this ugly way

```r
matrix %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  mutate(group=row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("SM_"), names_to="date", names_prefix="SM_") %>%
  mutate(value = as.numeric(as.character(value)),
         across(c(SOS, EOS, date), ymd), 
         ind = date %within% interval(SOS, EOS)) %>%
  group_by(group, ind) %>%
  summarise(maximum = as.factor(max(value)), .groups="drop_last") %>%
  filter(ind | is.na(ind)) %>%
  pull(maximum) %>%
  cbind(as.data.frame(matrix),maximum=.) %>%
  as.matrix()
```

gives (just the last four columns):

```r
     SM_2001.12.21       SOS          EOS          maximum            
[1,] "0.835780441761017" "2001.06.09" "2001.10.03" "0.884132504463196"
[2,] "0.831098616123199" "2001.06.14" "2001.09.27" "0.874269723892212"
[3,] "0.74629545211792"  "2001.06.13" "2001.09.18" "0.872524857521057"
[4,] "0.763430953025818" "2001.07.27" "2001.10.29" "0.901106178760529"
[5,] "0.768242657184601" "2001.06.30" "2001.10.01" "0.879017233848572"
[6,] "0.796047866344452" "2001.06.10" "2001.10.01" "0.884612858295441"
```

Answer (score 3):

First and foremost, a loop would achieve the same (or possibly faster) speed compared to using `*apply`. Regardless of how one puts it, these functions simply implements loops efficiently and safely.

As for how we can achieve it, we will have to iterate over each element regardless, so assuming your data is stored in `d` (with the above structure)

```
d <- as.data.frame(d)
#change column classes (to date and numeric). Note lapply iterates over columns
# d was original a matrix, and because numeric and date columns were present, they are all converted to 'character' columns
nc <- ncol(d)
numCol <- seq_len(nc - 2)
d[, numCol] <- lapply(d[, numCol], as.numeric)
d[, -numCol] <- lapply(d[, -numCol], as.Date, format = '%Y.%m.%d')
# Extract the date value of each column name
colDates <- colnames(d)[numCol]
colDates <- as.Date(gsub('^SM_', '', colDates), format = '%Y.%m.%d')
# define a 'between' function (similar to the one present in the data.table package) 
# Not as general (or fast) though
`%between%` <- function(x, y){
  mi <- min(y)
  ma <- max(y)
  x >= mi & x <= ma
}
# Finaly find the max value between each date, for each row
f <- function(x){
  # Get period (unlist for safety)
  period <- unlist(c(x['SOS'], x['EOS']))
  #Find max using our new %between% function. 
  #Note: 
  # use na.rm = TRUE to remove possible na values.
  # apply also changes d to a matrix, and because of this numeric columns turn into characters (there's a date column). So i use as.numeric to change it back.
  max(as.numeric(x[colDates %between% period]), na.rm = TRUE)
}
(d$max <- apply(d, 1, f))
0.8841325 0.8742697 0.8725249 0.9011062 0.8790172 0.8846129
```

Note here, there are 3 different loops going on. 2 for the first 2 lapply's, and 1 for the final apply.